# Chocolate spread preservation

Tags: food-safety

I have tried and made chocolate spread at home. I made it using a melted milk chocolate slab added to boiled Amul fresh cream. After a few days, it grew some fungus. How can its life be increased? What should be added to act as a preservative and in what ratio? It was kept in a plastic container under normal room temperature as I want to sell it in market. Also, what precautions can be taken before sealing the containers? What is the minimum life expected in a sealed plastic container under room temperature? 1litr boiled fresh cream mixed with 1.2 kg of melted chocolate slab.

Comment: What kind of ratio of cream and chocolate are you using? Chocolate won't usually mold easily, so maybe it's a fair amount of cream?

Answer (score 1):

Use sterilised glass jar/s similar to jam making and pickling, you can place some plastic wrap (cling film) over the top of the jar before sealing as an additional air/moisture barrier.  Also think of possibly dividing into smaller portions.